# typename as return type of operator overloading function in c++

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, typename

Why is the keyword `typename` used in the return type of the [operator overloading](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp)? How having it makes difference?

```
typename boost::detail::sp_member_access< T >::type operator-> () const 
{
    BOOST_ASSERT( px != 0 );
    return px;
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB FGITW-ed me to the dupevote :)

Comment: @sehe: Training, habit, fast F5-cycles, and a helpful heuristic that prepopulated the answer!

Comment: My failure was due to writing "When" initially, instead of "Where". :(

Comment: No one liner answer. Have to read that long post.. :|

Comment: @SauravSahu: Oh no! You have to _read_ and _study_ in order to _understand_! Whatever will you do!! Seriously, you will not go very far with that level of laziness. Your profile says you're a good enough engineer to be employed by Microsoft, so surely you understand the value of spending ten minutes reading and studying some documentation?

Comment: Thanks.. I like reading and learning from you guys...going through the post...:)

Comment: EVEN BETTER. No need to read it at all. Just accept that `template` is there, and don't worry about it :/